# Change a style selector in a CSSStyleSheet using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a CSS custom property that I'm trying to change on the fly using vanilla JavaScript. I have created a new `CSSStyleSheet` object and I have added styles to it already using the code below.

```
let sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
sheet.insertRule(".color3.shade500 {--lightness: 0; --chroma: 0; --hue: 0}");
```

The problem I'm having is I would like to change a single property within a given `CSSStyleRule` and I'm not having any luck. These need to be changed based on the value of an input on the page. I can access the correct `CSSStyleRule` using the code below that is part of a for loop.

```
console.log(sheet.rules[y].selectorText);
```

This results in the following being printed to the console:

```
CSSStyleRule {selectorText: '.color3.shade500', style: CSSStyleDeclaration, styleMap: StylePropertyMap, cssRules: CSSRuleList, type: 1, ...}
  cssRules: CSSRuleList {length: 0}
  cssText: ".color3.shade500 { --lightness: 0; --chroma: 0; --hue: 0; }"
  parentRule: null
  parentStyleSheet: CSSStyleSheet {ownerRule: null, cssRules: CSSRuleList, rules: CSSRuleList, type: 'text/css', href: null, ...}
  selectorText: ".color3.shade500"
  style: CSSStyleDeclaration {0: '--lightness', 1: '--chroma', 2: '--hue', accentColor: '', additiveSymbols: '', alignContent: '', alignItems: '', alignSelf: '', ...}
  styleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 3}
  type: 1
  [[Prototype]]: CSSStyleRule
```

My question is what command would I use to update a single property while leaving the other properties in the rule alone? I have found documentation on the `CSSStyleSheet` function on the Mozilla developer website [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), but I haven't been successful in trying to implement the `replace()` function nor do I know if that is even the correct one to be using.

Comment: An option would be to add a second CSS rule with a 3rd class on the element that you can dynamically add with Javascript.

You typically don't want to change your CSS itself so adding/removing another class to the element and having an existing rule for those specifiers would allow you to toggle by updating the DOM.

Comment: That's not an option as there are about 200 elements in which the three properties can be adjusted, and the properties are controlled by an input box which the user can adjust to their liking. Therefore, having a couple preset classes will not sufficiently cover the full spectrum of colors available. This project is for a color palette generator that not only allows the user to select a full spectrum of colors, but also allows the user to set up 10 different tints of the selected colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the `setProperty()` method on a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object. The `CSSStyleDeclaration` interface represents an object that is a CSS declaration block, and exposes style information and various style-related methods and properties. In your question, you shared the results of

```
console.log(sheet.rules[y].selectorText)
```

which contains the `CSSStyleDeclaration` object as the 6th key/value pair. To access the object, we can use the `CSSStyleSheet` API by using

```
document.styleSheets[x].cssRules[y].style
```

In your question, you already have the `CSSStyleSheet` contained in the `sheet` variable, so we would rewrite it to say

```
sheet.cssRules[y].style
```

Then we can modify the existing CSS custom property, or create a new property if there wasn't already a key/value pair for it, in the declaration block by using the `setProperty()` method. The `CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()` method interface sets a new value for a property on a CSS style declaration object.

## Syntax

```
setProperty(propertyName, value)
setProperty(propertyName, value, priority)
```

### Parameters

`propertyName`

A string representing the CSS property name (hyphen case) to be modified.

`value` optional

A string containing the new property value. If not specified, treated as the empty string.

`priority` optional

A string allowing the `!important` CSS priority to be set. If this is not specified, it is treated as the empty string. The following values are accepted:

- String value `"important"`
- Keyword `undefined`
- String empty value `""`

### Return Value

None (`undefined`)

### Exceptions

`NoModificationAllowedError` `DOMException`
This is thrown if the property or declaration block is read only.

## Alternative Usage

If `priority` can be omitted, the following syntax can be used instead:

style.cssPropertyName = "value";

## SOLUTION

Based on your question, code samples, and comment, what you are trying to accomplish sounds very similar to the example listed on the setProperty documentation page of the mdn web docs found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty#examples).

In your project you have three inputs that can be set to dynamically change the color swatch lightness, chroma, and hue, in a color palette generator.

We know that the rule we need to alter in order to accomplish this is contained in the `CSSStyleSheet` that you created and stored in the `sheet` variable. Therefore, we can loop through the rules contained in this stylesheet, which are located in the `stylesheet.cssRules` array. For each one we will check to see if its CSSStyleRule.selectorText property is equal to the selector `.color3.shade500`, which is the one we are looking for.

If we find a match, we need to store a reference to this CSSStyleRule object in a variable. We can then update the rule with the new value. This is done with the `setProperty()` method.

```
if (".color3.shade500" === sheet.cssRules[y].selectorText) {
  let styleInstance = sheet.cssRules[y].style;
  styleInstance.setProperty("--lightness", lightness);
}
```

[CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) [setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)